# change dataframe column headings with str function

Tags: pandas

I am trying to change the existing column headings of a dataframe.

I have these headers:

```
headers = df.columns.values
print(headers)
['Period Ending:' '201931/12' '201831/12' '201731/12' '201631/12']
```

I want to have this:

```
['year' '2019' '2018' '2017' '2016']
```

The code I have is this:

```
a = headers[1].str[:4]
b = headers[2].str[:4]
c = headers[3].str[:4]
d = headers[4].str[:4]
headers = ['year', a, b, c, d]
df.columns = headers
print(df)
```

But it is returning this:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First slice all columns without first by `[1:]` and then slice first 4 letters by `str[:4]`, convert to list and prepend `[year]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Period Ending:', '201931/12', '201831/12',
                           '201731/12', '201631/12'])
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Period Ending:, 201931/12, 201831/12, 201731/12, 201631/12]
Index: []
```

---

```
print (df.columns[1:])
Index(['201931/12', '201831/12', '201731/12', '201631/12'], dtype='object')
print (df.columns[1:].str[:4])
Index(['2019', '2018', '2017', '2016'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
df.columns = ['year'] + df.columns[1:].str[:4].tolist()
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [year, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016]
Index: []
```